# Button with ControlTemplate - incorrect background

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a little Minesweeper clone in WPF. I have the following style for a tile that is exposed (i.e. not hidden):

```
<Style x:Key="ExposedTile" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I set the background colour of mines in code when the user clicks on a tile that conceals a mine:

```
button.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
```

For some reason, instead of the background of the whole button, only the background of the text in the button is being set:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**edit**: This code executes when a mine button is clicked:

```
button.Style = this.Resources["ExposedTile"] as Style;

if (button == explodedMineTile)
    button.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
else
    button.Background = Brushes.DarkOrange;
```

Comment: add the code that happens on the click of a button pleases where the * is given

Comment: Done, but I don't see how it should help.

Comment: post ExposedTile Style please , i'm guessing you have a horizontalAlignment of center

Comment: It's the first thing in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need strictly set the `Width` and `Height` for `Button`. By default `Width` and `Height` is taken along the length of the content. Example:

`XAML`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ExposedTile" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Name="FlatButton"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Content="*" /> 
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlatButton.Style = this.Resources["ExposedTile"] as Style;

        FlatButton.Background = Brushes.Orange;            
    }
}
```

`Output`

[image]

Comment: Great, it works. The only downside is that I'd like the buttons to resize automatically if the window is resized, and setting fixed dimensions doesn't really facilitate that. Do you have a way of catering for this as well?

Comment: @Gigi: Are you using `UniformGrid`?

Comment: Yes. If I resize the window with your solution, the grid cells do get larger, but the buttons don't. Note that the grid cells actually contain border objects that contain the buttons (which is how the gridlines appear). I got this working by setting the background of the Border object to orange instead of the button itself, but your solution is far more elegant if the resizing issue can be addressed.

Comment: @Gigi: Try for buttons set `MinWidth = 25` and `MinHeight = 25`, instead of `Width` and `Height`.

Comment: It worked when I set those dimensions to the Border object (not the Button that it contains), so you get the points. :)

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev why Center and not Stretch ?

Comment: @eran otzap: Test self, star (`*`) in this case will is left, not centered. I thought that the author needs it to be in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the border in your control template doesn't have the full width of your tile.
So you could set the width of the border using template binding.
I hope this works...

```
<Style x:Key="ExposedTile" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```